# "echo: write error: invalid argument" writing to sysfs

Tags: gentoo, echo, sysfs, bcache

From the instructions for setting up bcache:

```
echo cset.uuid > /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/attach
```

What happens:

```
root@gentooserver ~ # echo 45511b33-6bb8-42d5-a255-3de1749f8dda > /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/attach
-su: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Try writing the variable `cset.uuid`, i.e run `echo cset.uuid > /sys/block/bcache0/bcache/attach`

Comment: Doesn't work. Same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backing drives have a 512B sector size and I had set the cache to use 4K.